# How do I replace os.system("mkdir " _testName) with subprocess.call in Python?

Tags: python, subprocess, os.system

How do I replace `os.system("mkdir " + _testName)` with `subprocess.call()` in Python?

`mkdir` is the unix command I want to run. `_testName` is a variable that is defined in the python script.

Comment: Why not use the python os module to make directories for you without using a system call

Comment: Hopefully `_testName` doesn't contain spaces or any other characters that will be interpreted by the shell. `subprocess.call()` will handle it ok, but the `os.system()` is a disaster waiting to happen

Answer (score 6):

without subprocess: [os.mkdir](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.mkdir)

with subprocess:

```
subprocess.call(['mkdir',_testName])
```

Or, if you want to make sure you were successful:

```
subprocess.check_call(['mkdir', _testName])
```